# Why do global native objects cause problems in C++/CLI dlls?

Tags: .net, interop, c++-cli

I have read somewhere that it has something to do with non-simple global native objects that have constructors/destructors. Can someone explain what it is exactly that may cause trouble?

Answer (score 4):

An Example: Once I tried to link a native C++ lib into a C++/CLI application. That lib contained a `const static std::string`. The application did always crash. Reason:

When the application starts, it initializes the const static objects. To make sure that the static objects get deleted properly on application exit, the compiler generates a call to the standard library function [atexit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atexit/). This call causes a crash in the native C runtime, which is not yet properly initialized at this point in time.

There is no problem with non-const static fields, which are initialized later.

I consider this as a bug - maybe it is fixed in the meantime (I had the problem with Visual Studio 2005). Unfortunately, I cannot provide an appropriate link, but I hope this helps for your further research.