# Strange behaviour of new operator in cli project

Tags: c++-cli

In a non-static function of native class of a cli c++ project I assign new memory space to 2 fields of the object:

```
Name = new wchar_t[50];
Type = new wchar_t[50];
```

where Name and Type are declared as:

```
class MyClass
{
...
 whcar_t *Name;
 whcar_t *Type;
...
}
```

The problem is that after allocating memory, Name and Type fields **point to the same memory**. How can it be fixed?

**UPDATE:**

The same address returns for EVERY NEW I cast. `new SomeClass()` returns the same pointer as `new wchar_t[50]`! May it be connected to some bug allocating native memory in cli project?

**UPDATE 2**

[Native class, which fields are initialized in cli class](http://pastebin.com/VdEbtQKU)

[Managed class definition](http://pastebin.com/cjvZCTBY)

[Managed class function, where Terminal used](http://pastebin.com/ihZEgMmF)

Memory allocation doesn't work with malloc, calloc, new operator, but works using LocalAlloc and static allocation like `wchar_t Name[50]`. It is very hard to find a reason of bad allocation, as I understand, but I even do not know, which is this sign of? Heap corruption, as @Hans Passant said? Or it may be OS failure or bug of some kind of custom AutoCad memory allocation? Is there any way to find which heap are used to allocate memory on current line of code?

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Replacing objects initialization from stack-based to heap solved the problem.

Comment: How are you determining that `Name` and `Type` are pointing to the same memory?

Comment: Can you please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits this problem?

Comment: @EricFinn, am looking for their values in debugger after assigning.

Comment: Looking at their assigned *addresses*, or looking at the *contents* of what they point to?

Comment: @FLCL How about doing a `printf("%p %p\n", Name, Type);`? That'll give you the actual addresses.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, addresses of course.

Comment: How about you copy something into one of them and then print the other? This should make things a little bit clearer ...

Comment: @EricFinn, in watch (Name == Type) are True.

Comment: Oh and by the way, is there a reason you're not using `std::wstring`?

Comment: I don't suppose you're using them both in an union, are you?

Comment: @FLCL I've seen debuggers report incorrect information at times. The behavior you're seeing is just odd enough that it seems far likelier that the tool you're using to observe the behavior is broken than the behavior is occurring, unless there's other relevant code that's not in your question (like a user-defined `operator new`).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, it will not fix the situation, because the same address returns for EVERY NEW I cast, as it turned out. new SomeClass() returns the same pointer as new wchar_t[50]!

Comment: @EricFinn, print returns two same strings.

Comment: @FLCL Have you perhaps made your own `operator new`, or using a library which overrides `operator new`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, no I have not override it. In my another cli project with the similar structure allocation works fine.

Comment: @FLCL Well, it looks like you've stumped StackOverflow, at least for now. Are you sure you don't get any results when searching the solution for `operator new`? Also, what do you get when you make multiple calls to `malloc` (in `<cstdlib>`)? If `operator new` uses `malloc` underneath and `malloc` has had its behavior changed, that might also be the cause.

Comment: @EricFinn, new, malloc(), calloc() return equal results. Only LocalAlloc returns diffrent pointers.

Comment: @FLCL Okay, I'd update the question with that information. And is this part of a larger project or is it pretty much just that one class with those two members and the constructor doing those allocations? Can you reproduce with a small chunk of code? Also, I'd step into malloc when debugging to see what definition it's using.

Comment: @EricFinn, I have pasted the code, but it is very simple and I have done such things in other projects before and everything works fine there. malloc is from stdlib.h which from MSVS standard headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably have found the answer and it is *very* strange: statically created local objects in methods cause this memory allocation bug(?). After replacing `SomeType someVar;` in functions with `SomeType* someVar = new SomeType();` addresses of allocated memory become different. It's randomly found solution and I not absolutely sure, but then I have found such kind of situation described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424761/why-do-global-native-objects-cause-problems-in-c-cli-dlls), so it is may be an answer.

Comment: There's definitely some irony in that it is entirely normal for stack allocations to have the same address.  This doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @HansPassant, I have never written, that objects in stack have the same addresses. My problem is that new operator returns same addresses and answer is about when I replace stack allocation everywhere with heap(`SomeType someVar;` -> `SomeType* someVar = new SomeType();`) everything works fine.

Comment: No, I wrote that :)  That you found code that isn't affected by the corrupted heap doesn't mean that you fixed the heap corruption problem in your code.

Comment: Oh, I have understood what you mean only now) Also, yes, this is not 100% fix and that was not 100% bug. Now I'm getting some "access to corrupted memory" errors and even if I change all memory allocations for objects of my classes to heap-based there a lot of things that I can not do without stack.

Answer (score 2):

These kind of problems are routinely explained by *heap corruption*.  The bane of any program that uses C strings and uses magic numbers like 50.  It takes but a string with 50 or more characters copied into that field and you've destroyed the integrity of the heap.  What happens next is quite unpredictable, getting the allocator to repeatedly return the same heap block is certainly not impossible.

Counter-measures are using smarter C++ classes that manage the memory for you, like std::wstring.  And a debug allocator, the kind you get out of `#include <crtdbg.h>`.  As well as various other memory debugging tools, it used to be a lively tool market segment.  And of course using managed code instead of native code, memory management mishaps is a large reason why managed code was invented in the first place.  Debugging a heap corruption problem can be *very* painful, good luck with it.